# Tracking updates for an individual paper in arXiv

Tags: arxiv

Albeit arXiv offers [RSS news feeds for subject areas updates](http://arxiv.org/help/rss), it is also possible to track an individual paper for updates (such as if it was submitted and/or accepted to a journal)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty silly solution, but you can [use a page tracking service](https://www.google.com/search?q=email+when+page+changes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to see when the page changes; this should detect both changes in the paper as well as in the journal its submitted to.

**Edited as per [Jaap Eldering](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/1605/jaap-eldering)'s suggestions in the comments:** you can use arXiv's OAI-PMH protocol to programmatically access version history! For example, if you want to look up [arXiv #1206.0094](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.0094), you can look up http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=GetRecord&identifier=oai:arXiv.org:1206.0094&metadataPrefix=arXivRaw for its version history.

Furthermore, arXiv **does** have an [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) feed for individual articles: you can access it at http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=1206.0094 -- the link it includes is to the latest version of the article, so I presume it will change if the article is updated.

Comment: Dear Gaurav, that is a good idea. Unfortunately, arXiv blocks page tracking services by its robots.txt.

Comment: Instead of trying to track the normal webpage for the paper, you could track the page by one of the means listed on http://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data, e.g. the arXivRaw format.

Comment: @JaapEldering Those are excellent suggestions -- I've incorporated them into my answer! If you want to add them to your own answer, I'll delete them from mine.

Comment: No problem, you can have them ;-)

Answer (score 4):

These updates get announced in the [email digest](http://arxiv.org/help/subscribe), don't they? So, you could subscribe to the appropriate email digest and filter for messages that contain the URLs of the papers you're interested in.

Comment: There is an exception that might be important: after version 5 of a paper, any further updates are [not announced](http://arxiv.org/help/replace#announcements) in the email digest.  So if the authors are prolific with their updates, this may not help.

Comment: @NateEldredge - that's a good point and one I hadn't been aware of. Gaurav and JaapEldering's amended solution might be better, then.